# How to find the index of an element in a list which is minimum in a sublist of that list in Python?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Assume I have a Python list:

```
x = [3,6,4,8,1,9]
```

and I want to find the index of the element in the list which is the minimum inside a sublist (say from index **2** to **4**).

So I want to take a sublist `x[2:5]` and get the index of the minimum element (in this case `x[4]`).

How to return index 4 in such a case? If I use np.argmin() on the sublist, it will return the index according to the sublist (in this case, np.argmin(x[2:5]) will return 2 which is correct according to the sublist).

I don't want to use multiple if-else conditions. How to go about getting this index in a short way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the index where the sublist starts, and you'll have your original index:

```
x = [3,6,4,8,1,9]
subl_start = 2
subl_end = 5

ind_min = np.argmin(x[subl_start: subl_end]) + subl_start
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems like I was so close, just had to think a step ahead.

Answer (score 2):

You can also find the minimum of numbers between a threshold:

```
>>> x = [3,6,4,8,1,9]
>>> start, end = 2, 5
>>> min((e, i) for i, e in enumerate(x) if start <= i < end)[1]
4
```

Or incrementing the final result index:

```
>>> min((e, i) for i, e in enumerate(x[start:end]))[1] + start
4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one liner will do fine for your case.

```
x.index(min(x[2:5]))
```

you can replace 2 & 5 with some variables also. (for index n to m -> (arr[n:m+1]))